# org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, weblogic, ivy, xerces

My problem is similar [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805360/classcastexception-org-apache-xerces-parsers-xincludeawareparserconfiguration-c) but I am trying this on  intellij Idea Ultimate (2018.1.3) instead of Eclipse and answers suggested there are not working for me.

My project uses ivy for dependency management and I have xerces 2.8 and 2.11 in my classpath due to transitive dependencies. I am using jdk8 to build the project and when I try to deply my web application in WebLogic 12.1.3 I am getting below exception,

```
aused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.xml.XMLFactory.getDOMParser(XMLFactory.java:107)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLErrorCodeReader.parse(SQLErrorCodeReader.java:108)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.endConfiguration(DBDictionary.java:4096)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.OracleDictionary.endConfiguration(OracleDictionary.java:170)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:505)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:430)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionaryFactory.newDBDictionary(DBDictionaryFactory.java:199)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionaryFactory.newDBDictionary(DBDictionaryFactory.java:66)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getDBDictionaryInstance(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:530)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.endConfiguration(MappingRepository.java:1250)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:505)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:430)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.PluginValue.instantiate(PluginValue.java:103)
at org.apache.openjpa.conf.MetaDataRepositoryValue.instantiate(MetaDataRepositoryValue.java:68)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ObjectValue.instantiate(ObjectValue.java:83)
at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.newMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:843)
at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.getMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:834)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.initialize(BrokerImpl.java:292)
at kodo.kernel.KodoBroker.initialize(KodoBroker.java:32)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.initializeBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:216)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:190)
... 44 common frames omitted
```

I have tried adding below parameters in my classpath server starts successfully but our code needs Xerces versions of these file so all my APIs fail.

```
-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactor
```

This is working without any change in eclipse I need to get it working on intellij please help.

Comment: Eclipse has an explicit order list for dependencies, check the order of your Xerces libraries there and try reordering your Xerces versions in ivy or excluding the offending Xerces version.

Comment: I am using intellij Idea

Comment: Check the artifact configuration, make sure the libraries in the artifact you deploy are ordered the same way as in Eclipse: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html.